# Tkinter, seguir utilizando programa mientras se ejecuta un while

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Buenas Tardes,
Hago un programa donde se toman dos fechas por parte del usuario y luego una comparación con un While, me gustaría seguir utilizando el programa mientras el While se ejecuta, existe alguna forma ?

```
def callback():
    var=OpenHour.get()
    var1=CloseHour.get()
    actual = 0
    if not validateDate(var, var1):
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Error","Datos o formato incorrecto, deberia ser hh:mm")
    else:
        while var != actual:
            actual = datetime.datetime.now().time().strftime('%H:%M')
        print "ya acabe voy al second while"
        while var1 != actual:
            actual = datetime.datetime.now().time().strftime('%H:%M')
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Exito","Se ha terminado el ciclo")

        #tkMessageBox.showinfo("Exito","La programacion se ha \nrealizado de la manera correcta")
b = Button(VentanaPersiana, text="Programar", width=10, command=callback)
b.pack()
```

Comment: Buenas! Posiblemente tu lo que estés buscando es ejecutar dos trozos de código a la vez (o más). Si se puede, no es tarea sencilla si no sabes usar threads. 

Con ello podrás hacer que tu while se ejecute mientras realizas otras tareas sin hacer que la verificación sea bloqueante.
Te dejo un link que te será de ayuda.
http://www.genbetadev.com/python/multiprocesamiento-en-python-threads-a-fondo-introduccion

Comment: Como bien lo menciona Idir, usa hilos...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La respuesta es, como te han comentado, usar hilos mediante [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html). Lo que pasa es que no es tan simple, en principio **[`Tkinter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html) no es thread-safe** lo que nos obliga a correr todo el código de nuestra interfaz gráfica desde el hilo principal.

En tu ejemplo podriamos pensar que simplemente ejecutamos la función `callback()` en un hilo secundario y problema resuelto. Pues no, eso sería si no necesitas usar datos creados en la función en tu GUI o si no necesitas actualizar o crear widgets (como haces tu con `tkMessageBox`) desde este hilo secundario.

La prefunta es ¿Y ahora que hacemos?

Pues bien, la solución es usar colas ([`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html)) que son thread-safe y permiten compartir información entre hilos. La idea es simple, creamos una cola y la información que tengamos que pasar al hilo principal donde ejecutamos [`Tkinter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html) la ponemos en la cola. Como es lógico, necesitamos una función en el hilo principal que periodicamente mire si hay algo en la cola y si lo hay lo procese.

Esta función requiere ser ejecutada periódicamente, para ello podriamos usar el clásico `while True` acompañado de un tiempo de espera entre ciclo para no cabrear al procesador, para ello usariamos [`time.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html). Pero hay un problema, con esto bloqueamos la interfaz gráfica y estamos en el mismo problema que al principio, para solucionarlo simplemente tiramos del método `after()` de Tkinter.

Usando tu ejemplo quedaria algo así:

```
import datetime
import time
import threading
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import Queue

cola = Queue.Queue()

def validateDate(a,b):
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(a, '%H:%M')
        datetime.datetime.strptime(b, '%H:%M')
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def callback():
    def run():
        var=OpenHour.get()
        var1=CloseHour.get()
        actual = 0

        if not validateDate(var, var1):
            cola.put((tkMessageBox.showinfo, ("Error", "Datos o formato incorrecto, deberia ser hh:mm"), {} ))

        else:
            while var != actual:
                actual = datetime.datetime.now().time().strftime('%H:%M')
                time.sleep(1)
            cola.put((tkMessageBox.showinfo, ("Exito", "La persiana se ha abierto"), {}))

            while var1 != actual:
                actual = datetime.datetime.now().time().strftime('%H:%M')
                time.sleep(1)
            cola.put((tkMessageBox.showinfo, ("Exito", "La persiana se ha cerrado"), {}))

    t=threading.Thread(target=run)
    t.start()

def tkloop():
    try:
        while True:
            funcion, args, kwargs  = cola.get_nowait()
            funcion(*args, **kwargs)
    except:
        pass

    VentanaPersiana.after(100, tkloop)

VentanaPersiana = Tk()
l1=Label(VentanaPersiana, text='Hora de apertura:')
l1.pack()
OpenHour = Entry()
OpenHour.pack()
l2=Label(VentanaPersiana, text='Hora de cierre:')
l2.pack()
CloseHour = Entry()
CloseHour.pack()
b = Button(VentanaPersiana, text="Programar", width=10, command=callback)
b.pack()
tkloop()
VentanaPersiana.mainloop()
```

Realmente exite otra posibilidad que es usar Callbacks mediante el uso de `after()` o de `after_idle()` y sin usar hilos, esto tiene algunos problemas y para mi gusto se hace pesado en códigos medianamente complejos, te dejo un ejemplo simplificado (tu código habria que modificarlo bastante para que funcionara de esta forma) de un temporizador en el que salta un `tkMessageBox` cuando es la hora indicada en el `Entry`:

```
import datetime
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox



def iniciar():
    def callback():
        actual = datetime.datetime.now().time()
        var = hour.get()
        var = datetime.datetime.strptime(var, '%H:%M')
        if var.time() < actual:
            tkMessageBox.showinfo("Aviso", "Hora de hacer algo...")
        else:
            root.after_idle(callback)
    root.after_idle(callback)



root = Tk()
l=Label(root, text='Introducir hora de la forma HH:MM:')
l.pack()
hour = Entry()
hour.pack()
b = Button(root, text="Temporizador", width=10, command=iniciar)
b.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

**Nota**: en el primer ejemplo he añadido cosas que no están en tu ejemplo para hacer un código mínimamente funcional y ejecutable para terceros. Funcionan en `Python 2.x` ya que tu código es para esta rama.

Saludos.

Comment: Mas que excelente, muy buena explicación. Gracias por la ayuda (y)

Comment: Te amo justo necesitaba esto